# CherryPy How to respond with JSON?

Tags: jquery, python, json, cherrypy

In my controller/request-handler, I have the following code:

```
def monkey(self, **kwargs):
  cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
  message = {"message" : "Hello World!" }
  return message
monkey.exposed = True
```

And, in my view, I've got this javascript:

```
$(function() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  $.ajaxSetup({ 
    scriptCharset : "utf-8",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  });
  $.post("http://localhost/wsgi/raspberry/monkey", "somePostData",
    function(data) {
      try{
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        body.innerHTML += "<span class='notify'>" + response + "</span>";
      }catch(e){ 
        body.innerHTML += "<span class='error'>" + e + "</span>";
      }
    }
  );
});
```

And finally, here's my problem.  I get no JSON response and I'm not sure why.

Secondly, would someone be able to explain how to format data in my controller/request-handler response as a JSON response in the simplest way possible, without using tools?

Comment: Do you know that CherryPy supplies a decorator for exposing functions? Just put `@cherrypy.exposed` on the line above the `def monkey...`

Comment: Note that the correct decorator is now `@cherrypy.expose`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "without using tools" -- Python **is** "a tool", right?

With just Python and its standard library (2.6 or better), add at the top of your module

```
import json
```

and change the `return` statement to

```
return json.dumps(message)
```

Comment: In Python 2.5, you can use the [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) package.

Comment: Actually, what I meant by saying "without tools" was without using decorators.  I'm still getting used to python's idiosyncrasies.  Yes, I have seen simplejson used, but I want to be able to do it using the base libraries first.

Comment: @Sean, `simplejson` is just the older version of `json`, from before the latter was incorporated into the Python standard library. IOW, `json` is not any more "base" than `simplejson`, it's just a "packaging" decision by the PSF (specifically by the core developers of Python itself and the standard library that goes with it).

Comment: "Tool" is CherryPy jargon for "plugin". There's a whole subsystem for using them and making your own: http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/intro/concepts/tools.html

Comment: with this approach, you need to call
`cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'` to set the correct content type. however you shoul rather use `@cherrypy.tools.json_out()` instead

Answer (score 46):

Since CherryPy 3.2 there are tools to accept/return JSON:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def monkey(self, **params):
    return {"message": "Hello World!"}
```

Using `json_out` serializes the output and sets the appropriate Content-Type header for you.

Similarly decorating with `@cherrypy.tools.json_in()` can automatically accept/decode JSON post requests.

Comment: Thanks for this.  In reading Alex's post above and doing some testing on my own, I realize that your suggestion is more succinct, explicit, and readable than using JSON.dumps().

Comment: CherryPy 3.2 has been released, by the way :)

Comment: Here's the documentation for json_out: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/refman/lib/jsontools.html?#cherrypy.lib.jsontools.json_out

Comment: The above documentation is now at http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.lib.html?highlight=json_out#cherrypy.lib.jsontools.json_out